# Explain the equation and its answer

Tags: post-increment, decrement, pre-increment

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int x=3;
    int y;
    y = x+ (--x) + (x++) + x + (++x);
    cout << y << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output of is 13. But it should be 14.
Any explanation please ???????

Comment: Order of evaluation of any part of any expression is unspecified in C++.. Check [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) out.